# Help proving if $\Sigma\cup\theta\vdash\phi$ then $\Sigma\vdash(\theta\rightarrow\phi)$

Tags: logic

For context this is one direction of the Deduction Theorem. And what I am trying to figure out is how the proof in Leary and Kristensen pg. 64, in particular, is supposed to work. They write:

> For the more difficult direction we will make use of Proposition 2.2.4.
> Suppose that $C=\{\phi : \Sigma\vdash(\theta\rightarrow\phi)\}$. If we show that $C$ contains $\Sigma\cup\theta$, $C$ contains all the axioms of $\Lambda$, and $C$ is closed under the rules of inference
> as noted in Proposition 2.2.4, then by that proposition we will know that $\{\phi :\Sigma\cup\theta\vdash\phi\}\subseteq C$. In other words, we will know that if $\Sigma\cup\theta\vdash\phi$, then $\Sigma\vdash(\theta\rightarrow\phi)$, which is what we need to show.

Proposition 2.2.4 states that $Thm_\Sigma=\{\phi:\Sigma\vdash\phi\}$ is the "smallest set" containing all the axioms and closed under the rules of inference.

What I don't understand is how establishing that $C$ has these properties proves the direction they say it does. If we suppose $C=\{\phi : \Sigma\vdash(\theta\rightarrow\phi)\}$ and then show that $\{\phi :\Sigma\cup\theta\vdash\phi\}\subseteq C$, don't we show the opposite direction of what they say we show, namely that if $\Sigma\vdash(\theta\rightarrow\phi)$, then $\Sigma\cup\theta\vdash\phi$?

I understand their proofs of how $C$ bears the properties they set out to prove it has. I just don't get, conceptually, how this shows what they claim it does. Thanks for any help. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Long comment*

Recall the def of Prop.2.2.4 about $\text {Thm}_{\Sigma}$.

In **Th.2.7.4 (The Deduction Theorem)** the authors prove that:

> $\text {Thm}_{\Sigma \cup \theta} = \{ \phi \mid \Sigma \cup \theta \vdash \phi \} \subseteq \{ \phi \mid \Sigma \vdash (\theta \to \phi) \}=C$.

If you agree with this, by definition of set inclusion we have that:

> if $\phi \in \text {Thm}_{\Sigma \cup \theta}$, then $\phi \in C$,

that, unwinding the definition of the two sets, means: if $\Sigma \cup \theta \vdash \phi$, then $\Sigma \vdash (\theta \to \phi)$.

Comment: Oh! That's super interesting/cool! Thanks, Mauro. As usual you're a huge help!

Comment: @beachtrees - you are welcome :-)